# User control in avalon dock and separate window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, window

I'm developing a bunch of user controls which do different things - like a maintenance screen, enquiry screen, report screen that sort of thing. Each screen has a dedicated purpose and a single user control holds all the functionality for the one screen.

I'm using avalondock and can place these user controls into LayoutDocuments. This creates a separate tab for each screen/user control. I've got a menu system setup so users can choose which screens they need access to. For each new screen I create a new LayoutDocument, add the appropriate control to it, then add the LayoutDocument to the Docking panel's children.

This is all working fine.

Avalon dock also has the feature of being able to drag out the layout document and make it float - you can also dock it somewhere else in the app if you wish.

I'd like to take this concept one step further: Being able to say right click on a layout document and choose "Make external window" (i'll work out the exact wording later). The effect of this action would be to create a new application with it's own icon in the task bar; being able to alt-tab between it and other apps;

Kind of like when you're in say Excel editing a document and you then open up a second instance of excel. In Windows 7 you get two excel icons in the task bar (one behind the other), and you can alt-tab between them.

This is nearly the behaviour that i'm after. However the second app isn't a full blown copy of the first; it has only the one user control that the user selected.

This is where i'm stuck and would like a bit of guidance.

I'm thinking that i'll probably need some kind of shell app where I can pass in the user control that I want. The shell would act as a window with title, X, minimising etc; the user control would then be the sole content of that shell. Use process.start to create new process and launch ?

Ideally i'd be able to pass in the same control in the same state as the user is currently viewing - so if for example they are part way through editing some customer record in a maintenance screen, then choose the "external window" option, that same customer record would appear in the new window.

Has anyone done something similar or offer advice if i'm on the right track ?

I think I know how to create a shell app but not sure on passing a user control to it dynamically. I'd like to avoid creating different shell apps for each user control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to start a new process for that scenario.

Just create a new `Window` add your `UserControl` at runtime and remove the UserControl from the `DockingManager`. Make sure the `Window` has `ShowInTaskbar` set if you want it to show up there.

To get the command to undock the `UserControl` as a seperate `Window` you just have to restyle the `ContextMenu` to incorporate your command (take a look at the VS2010 theme and how the `ContextMenu` is styled there [VS2010 theme.xaml](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/96370#1749982)).

Comment: He may need to if he wants it to shop up as more than one in the task bar

Comment: Thanks heaps ! That was waaaaaaaaay easier than I was expecting it to be !

Comment: I had success with the window, but trouble with the context menu. I've posted a another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925520/avalondock-override-contextmenu-cannot-find-the-type-contextmenuelement

Comment: I threw my 10 cents at the question you linked